# Visual Studio 2013 - cannot navigate to "namespace"

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, go-to-definition

[goto definition error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ytNv.png)

This "cannot navigate to 'namespace' error occurs after I right click and select go to definition on my project. I also tested doing this on other projects even making new one just to see if it is just my current projects. Yet it is still showing. I have also tried doing windows update and repairing Visual Studio 2013 but its not doing the job. I have read some cases and they blamed that because of working with 2 languages which is I do also but have worked with it for 5 months already and this error just went out 2 days ago. Is reinstalling visual studio 2013 gonna work? I am taking this as a last resort

Comment: Try removing and re-adding the reference with the specific version ?

Comment: Actually this is one of known issue you can solve it by reinstalling https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1577587

Comment: Really you cannot navigate to 'namespace', your visual is okay!

Comment: In Resharper there is a function called _Assembly Explorer_, which lets you decompile namespaces and show the source code, but with the standard VS I don't think this is possible

Comment: My vs2013 is alwasy like is, but thought it is work as designed and not issue.

Comment: i tried removing and re-adding the references and still it did not work. I dont think it is okay because there is a specific page that has a timer in it and im calling jquery ajax over there and it hangs up on that page. Actually a moment ago my team mate experienced this issue. We will try opening the project in visual studio 2010 and see if it appears different.

Comment: ok that was useless. lol project is incompatible with vs2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by javascript looping millionth times combined with a timer that loads every second. It caused 3 of my team's PC to loose the ability to use gotodefinition. Reinstalling Visual Studio however solved it.